# stsadm addsolution causes processor to hang

Tags: 2010, powershell, stsadm, solution

Running the `stsadm –o addsolution –filename tec.solzip.wsp` causes the processor to hang, running on SP2010. would anybody know any reason why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be custom code in `SPFeatureReceiver.FeatureInstalled` in one of the Features which is in that Solution.